# Reduce the length of a list for the next iteration

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to reduce the length of the List up to the indexes which were modified while traversal. However, I'm trying to avoid using another list in order save space. Is it possible to :

1. make this change.
2. Override a final function `lists.length`

```
public ListNode mergeKLists(ListNode[] lists) {
    int amount = 0;
    while(amount != 1){
        amount = 0;
        if(lists.length%2 == 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < lists.length; i++){
                lists[amount] = merge2lists(lists[i] , lists[i + 1]);
                amount++;
                i++;
            }
            lists.subList( 0 , amount - 1); //will not work
            lists.length = amount; // will not work
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: arrays are immutable so you can't change their length `lists.length = amount;` you have to create new array using arraycopy

Comment: then I can't use this condition for recursive purpose!

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh It's list not array. And creating different array while reducing length it's gonna cost additional space complexity.

Comment: @Lokesh yes! And I'm not sure about if lists are immutable.

Comment: @Lokesh i believe what i saw , have a look `ListNode[] lists`

Comment: @NehaGupta you can use list , use `clear()` to delete content and `addAll(anotherlist)` to add content of one list to another

Comment: @NehaGupta No they are not immutable. you can delete add elements

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Again as said if it's array it's gonna cost additional space complexity as you stated above. neha change it to list will be easy for you.

Comment: Don't create your own list implementation, avoid using of arrays. Java contains a Collections framework, Eclipse has an additional collection framework.

Comment: lists.subList().clear didn't work because lists is an object of ListNode.

Comment: Just a little note, **it is not recomended at all to change your data structure while you iterate on it**. You can always use helper variables that will indicate where you where on your last iteration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem using another variable which keeps the record of length.

```
public  ListNode mergeKLists(ListNode[] lists) {

    int amount = 0;
    int length = lists.length;
    while(amount!= 1){
        amount = 0;
        if(lists.length%2 == 0){
            for (int i=0; i<length; i++){
                lists[amount] = merge2lists(lists[i] , lists[i+1]);
                amount++;
                i++;
            }
           length = amount;
        }
        else{.....}
  }
```